# Spring mvc 3.1 tomcat 7 - 404 not resolving jsp but controller annotations working fine

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp, http-status-code-404

I have been working on this for a while now and simply have no idea what's wrong.  I am deploying a Spring 3.1 MVC app on Tomcat 7.  From looking at the DEBUG output, I can see that 1) The MVC dispatcher servlet gets all my URLs as required 2) any URLs mapped to controllers annotations works fine 3) Any URLs that need to be mapped to JSPs get a 404.  Also, I am using JDK 1.7.0_09.  My JSP pages are in /WEB-INF/jsp/.

Thanks in advance for any tips that I might be missing!

Here is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name></display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have tried modifying my URL pattern to /, /*, /.*, .  "/" seems to be taking my the farthest so far.  Also, I could be wrong, but I don't think the URL is the issue since the DEBUG logs show that all the URLs are going to the dispatcher servlet - which is what I want.

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!--Tell the servlet where to look for annotated methods-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.mvc.ctrl" />

    <!--Enables many annotations and searches for @Controller annotated methods etc.. -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--JSR-303 (Bean validation) support will be detected on classpath and enabled automatically-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (all extensions etc)-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping -->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />
</beans>
```

I try to send over a url of `http://localhost:8080/hello`.  My application is deployed to "/" and the resolver doesn't map the "/home" view to /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp despite the DEBUG logs showing that it properly acknowledges that "/home" is the incoming view name.

`http://localhost:8080/rest/user/bob_user` works great and is mapped to a Controller annotation.

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Update:
Here are the Debug logs for `http://localhost:8080/hello` which should translate to /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
2012-11-23 03:45:50,089 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/hello]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,089 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@5c9a010c] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2012-11-23 03:45:50,089 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /hello
2012-11-23 03:45:50,093 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/hello]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,093 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@49049c10] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2012-11-23 03:45:50,093 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/hello]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@17bd11ee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/hello]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@f212a54] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/hello] are [/**]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/hello] are {}
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/hello] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@4a61f88e] and 1 interceptor
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@1a33f07b]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@47f128ad]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,094 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/hello] is: -1
2012-11-23 03:45:50,095 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2012-11-23 03:45:50,095 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f38fd40
2012-11-23 03:45:50,095 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
2012-11-23 03:45:50,095 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/hello]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[D81D9C8BE397827739EB48BC3BB7A35D]; user=[null]; time=[7ms]; status=[OK]
2012-11-23 03:45:50,095 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/hello]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[D81D9C8BE397827739EB48BC3BB7A35D]; user=[null]; time=[7ms]; status=[OK]
```

Comment: Do u have a logging enabled? What does the log says?

Comment: I will update the post to reflect the debug logs...

Comment: And the controller returns `"home"`, right?

Comment: There is no controller/requestmapping for "hello".  I want it to be resolved to /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp directly but it sends back a 404.

Comment: How would the servlet guess that it should resolve `"home"` to  `"/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp"`?

Comment: Does controller returns "/home" or "home" as logical view name?

Comment: @PawelSolarski there is NO controller. I think that the OP expects that spring view resolver will somehow redirect `hello` to  "/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp"

Comment: I do have controllers but their requestmappings are "/rest/user/..." or something of that nature.  Those work just fine.  What I want is for something that doesn't map to the Controllers to be mapped to a JSP directly.  So when I do `http://localhost:8080/hello`, that goes to /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp.  When I hit `http://localhost:8080/rest/user/bob_user`, that goes to my controller that has a method mapped to `/rest/user/{username}`

Comment: so.. I got around this issue by creating a new Controller class that has a method with a `@RequestMapping("/{viewName}")`.  The way Spring MVC matches, this should be the last and most generic match.  As a result, if I get the URL, it will try to match the other Controllers first and then match this one the last.  When it does match, I just return a string with the view name so it will eventually go to /WEB-INF/jsp/view-name.jsp.  Anyone have a better idea?  Thanks!

Comment: why You need to specify your `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean? I think the problem will be resolved if you modify the id of your view resolver to `internalResourceViewResolver`.

Comment: I had to specify those adapters because my request mappings utilize the "accepts" and "consumes" option.  If I don't specify those, the "accepts" and "consumes" parameters don't work within the "@RequestMapping" annotation.  Also, changing the id of the resolver to `internalResourceViewResolver` had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mvc:annotation-driven  is overriding your RequestMappingHandlerMapping.

Also exclude @Controller classes from your component-scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

because the controllers are already found by

Answer (score 0):

so.. I got around this issue by creating a new Controller class that has a method with a `@RequestMapping("/{viewName}")`. The way Spring MVC matches, this should be the last and most generic match. As a result, if I get the URL, it will try to match the other Controllers first and then match this one the last. When it does match, I just return a string with the view name so it will eventually go to `/WEB-INF/jsp/[view-name].jsp`. Anyone have a better idea? Thanks!